# Un Ordered Customer

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, datetime

I have two tables fist one customer and second one Orderdetails. I want list of sign ups from 4th on wards and exclude the list of customers who have bought.

```
    SELECT *
FROM Customer
WHERE RegisteredDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'12/04/2015',101)) 
                         AND CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'12/07/2015',101)) 
 AND CustomerID NOT IN(SELECT *
                       FROM Customer c
                       INNER JOIN orderdetails od ON c.CustomerId = od.CustomerID
                       WHERE C.RegisteredDate 
                     BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'12/04/2015',101)) 
                         AND CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'12/07/2015',101)) 
                         AND Transactionid IS NOT NULL
                       )
```

the result is:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 13 Only one expression can be
>   specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with
>   EXISTS.

Answer (score 2):

Remove * (all columns) in subquery and specify select CustomerID  instead of  *(all columns)  in subquery.

Because when using **NOT IN**, it is expected that the number of columns return by the subquery is only one.

Comment: Should be `select c.CustomerID`, since the subquery joins 2 tables with a `CustomerID` column.

Comment: @aro_tech Yes it should be table_aliasname.column_name only.i.e c.CustomerID only

Comment: Thank you @Ajaynaidu Pappala

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answer IN operator only expects one column to be returned when being used with a sub-query, you should only select the cutomerID in the sub-query but if there is a chance of it returning NULL values then use EXISTS operator something like....

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer c1
WHERE RegisteredDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'12/04/2015',101) 
                         AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'12/07/2015',101) 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM Customer c
               INNER JOIN orderdetails od ON c.CustomerId = od.CustomerID
               WHERE C.RegisteredDate 
             BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'12/04/2015',101) 
                 AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'12/07/2015',101) 
                 AND Transactionid IS NOT NULL
                 AND C1.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
               )
```

Comment: Is it better to replace * with 1 in exists?

Comment: This conversion of datetime is really bad, should be convert(datetime,'12/04/2015',101), I know it was imported from the question but still ....

Comment: @bmsqldev the simple answer is no, it is not better to use 1 than *... you can even use 1/0 without getting an error. Try: SELECT 1 WHERE exists(SELECT 1/0)

Comment: there is a misconception about this `*` when it is being used with the exists operator, nothings ever gets returned with this `*` when it is being used with an EXISTS operator it is only checking for existence of any value which sometimes does work better than select A column. but yea true select 1 in the inner query would make things simpler :)

Comment: @t-clausen.dk agreed on the date suggestion :)

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I am not too familiar with MySql Data conversion, in SQL Server if we are converting a value to datetime then the culture variable is redundant, is it not also true for MySql too ???  This `CONVERT(DATETIME,'12/04/2015',101)` should really be just `CONVERT(DATETIME,'12/04/2015')`???

Comment: don't know about mysql either, actually is should just be '12/04/2015' without the conversion. But showing which conversion it being used is kind of nice

Comment: Thank you its Working @M.Ali

Answer (score 1):

You cant use `select *` in a subquery, you need to specify the column which in this case is customerid.

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer
WHERE RegisteredDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'12/04/2015',101)) 
                     AND CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'12/07/2015',101)) 
AND CustomerID NOT IN(SELECT c.CustomerID
                   FROM Customer c
                   INNER JOIN orderdetails od ON c.CustomerId = od.CustomerID
                   WHERE C.RegisteredDate 
                 BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'12/04/2015',101)) 
                     AND CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'12/07/2015',101)) 
                     AND Transactionid IS NOT NULL
                   )
```